# Prime numbers which end with $19, 39, 59, 79$ or $99$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

$\varphi(n)$ denotes the Euler’s totient function, $n$ denotes a natural number $> 1$ and $\sigma(n)$ is the
sum of the divisors of $n$. Consider the expression:  $$F(n)=\varphi(\sigma(\sigma(n))-1)+1$$

Conjecture:  if this ends with 59 or 79 then this number is always prime.

C++ Program here: https://sendeyo.com/show/a78e4491d7

I checked my conjecture up to $n=10^7$.

What do you think?

Comment: Do you mean you checked up to $n=40000$?  In that range, how many "good" $n$ did you find?

Comment: Try $n=86659$. Also is there a reason why $\phi(\sigma(\sigma(n))-1) + 1$ is not used instead?

Comment: I think $n=4801$ is a counter example.

Comment: Yes, I checked up ton n=40 000. I don't know how many "good" n I found. Now I try to check if there exists a counter-example with my C++ program.

Comment: There are counterexamples (I agree with @Sil  that $n=86659$ is a counterexample) but it does seem like you get a lot of primes this way.  Of course, it depends on factoring big numbers.

Comment: @B.Goddard  With $n=4801$, I get that $\varphi( \sigma_1(\sigma_1(4801))-1)+1=4201$, which isn't a candidate for the OP's conjecture, though it is a prime.  I don't believe that the OP is conjecturing that *all* primes of that form must end in one of those pairs.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your post, please check to ensure that I didn't change your meaning.  I changed the format of your function slightly...I don't understand why you phrased it as $|1-\sigma_1(\sigma_1(n))|$.  As the argument of the absolute value is always negative, it seems simpler to just write it as $\sigma_1(\sigma_1(n))-1$. If I am missing something then, of course, feel free to roll back that edit.

Comment: Your link to the code doesn't work.

Comment: @lulu  My little script had 1 mod 20 instead of -1 mod 20.  Live and don't learn, is my motto.

Comment: Thank you for the counter-example. So this question is solved.

Comment: In future I would use a more well-known site like Github to share your code, or just include it in the question! [Here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFjs0KgzAQhO-C7zAIgrEKppdSwauvIbEmNlRXielBxHfv2h86h2F34Bsmjr0dtfXICRK5gwyDGhUGNbadApXQz0G7Zr7bZLH9qL5OQiCHFDgdhJkcCJbgFPU6kRlkgTTFRZRhANbKlTVDn88aDmKcC1QV5BWKOtDkYZdmdjwnWX_cIY7IJybaiEv27N3D17buhxt185NjYo_En2mdVo8XU0M5yw==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) is a short Sage/Python program to find the smallest counterexample. [Here](https://gist.github.com/goedel-gang/2f11b9bf82e28f9c207e59a6b687def4) are the counterexamples up to $10^7$.

Comment: @Izaak van Dongen: thanks you! But I wonder if there are conterexample which ends with 59 or 79.

Answer (score 7):

$$\varphi(\sigma(\sigma(86659))-1)+1=201899=101\times 1999$$

$$\varphi(\sigma(\sigma(432251))-1)+1=1082119=59\times 18341$$

Answer (score 1):

$$F(29194758)=178136579=137^2\cdot 9491$$ is still a counterexample.

$$F(113547153)=409620359=16097\cdot 25447$$ is a counterexmaple for ending digits $59$.

By the way :

Even , if such an expression would only produce primes (with given ending digits) , the method to find primes in this way would not be very efficient.