# Prime numbers which end with $59$ or $79$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function, divisor-sum

This is the weak conjecture of [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834936/prime-numbers-which-end-with-19-39-59-79-or-99.\](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834936/prime-numbers-which-end-with-19-39-59-79-or-99.%5C)
$\varphi(n)$ denotes the Euler’s totient function, $n$ denotes a natural number $> 1$ and $\sigma(n)$ is the
sum of the divisors of $n$. Consider the expression:  $$F(n)=\varphi(\sigma(\sigma(n))-1)+1$$

Conjecture:  if this ends with 59 or 79 then this number is always prime.

I checked my conjecture up to $n=10^7$ with the help of a member (see the previous topic).

What do you think?

Comment: Please include a link of the previous topic in the question

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834936/prime-numbers-which-end-with-19-39-59-79-or-99) is the previous question. It has the same question there, too (also in your last comment). You should not post the question again here. Edit the title of your original question.

Comment: @Soham Saha: ok I edited. Dietrich Burde: my previous topic has not enough visibility and I think this is an interesting question.

Comment: (+1) , although the expression $F(n)$ appears to be quite arbitary. Why twice the sigma function ?

Answer (score 2):

It's still not true. There is

- $n = 29194758, F(n) = 178136579 = 137^2 \cdot 9491$
- $n = 113547153, F(n) = 409620359 = 16097 \cdot 25447$

These are the smallest examples found by a simple brute-force search in Sage, using [the code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFjs0KgzAQhO-C7zAIgrEKppdSwauvIbEmNlRXielBxHfv2h86h2F34Bsmjr0dtfXICRK5gwyDGhUGNbadApXQz0G7Zr7bZLH9qL5OQiCHFDgdhJkcCJbgFPU6kRlkgTTFRZRhANbKlTVDn88aDmKcC1QV5BWKOtDkYZdmdjwnWX_cIY7IJybaiEv27N3D17buhxt185NjYo_En2mdVo8XU0M5yw==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) I linked in my comment on your previous post.