# Prime numbers which end with 03, 23, 43, 63 or 83

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function, divisor-sum

This is inspired from this post: [Prime numbers which end with $19, 39, 59, 79$ or $99$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834936/prime-numbers-which-end-with-19-39-59-79-or-99)

Here I found a new formula:

$n$ is a natural number $>1$, $\varphi(n)$ denotes the Euler's totient function, $P_n$ is the $n^{th}$ prime number and $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of the divisors of n. Consider the expression:

$$F(n)=\varphi(|\sigma(n)-P_{n+2}|)+1$$

Conjecture: if this ends with 03, 23, 43, 63 or 83 then this number is always prime.

Example with $n=10270001113$, we have:

$$F(10270001113)=\varphi(\sigma(10270001113)-P_{10270001115})+1=\varphi(10468624896-259189944599)+1=248721319703$$ which is prime because it ends by 03.

Comment: Note that the linked conjecture turned out to be false.

Comment: @Peter: in fact, in the previous topic we found several counter-example. Is this the case here?

Comment: First counterexample is $F(680) =3243 = 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 163$. However, fascinatingly, for $n \le 350000$, all $14$ counterexamples have $P_{n+2} - \sigma(n) = p^2$ for some prime $p \in \{7, 19\} \pmod{20}$.

Comment: @Eric Snyder: thank you for the counterexample. Your conjecture is interesting. Any idea to proof it? I create a new subject.

Comment: I wouldn't bet on it being readily provable, or even calling it a conjecture! It's merely an observation. It's only the case up to a million (the program kept running), which of course an infinitesimally small portion of the number line, but not very long by other standards either.