# Square of prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function, divisor-sum

This conjecture is inspired by the comment of @Eric Snyder: [Prime numbers which end with 03, 23, 43, 63 or 83](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836413/prime-numbers-which-end-with-03-23-43-63-or-83)

$n$ is a natural number $>1$, $\varphi(n)$ denotes the Euler's totient function, $P_n$ is the $n^{th}$ prime number and $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of the divisors of n. Consider the expression:

$$F(n)=\varphi(|\sigma(n)-P_{n+2}|)+1$$

Conjecture: when $F(n) \equiv 3 \mod 20$ then this number is
a prime or $P_{n+2}-\sigma(n)=p^2$ (p prime) when the number is not a prime.

Examples:

$n=10270001113$, we have:

$$F(10270001113)=\varphi(\sigma(10270001113)-P_{10270001115})+1=\varphi(10468624896-259189944599)+1=248721319703$$ which is prime because it ends by 03.

A counterexample is found with n=680:

$$F(680)=\varphi(\sigma(680)-P_{680})+1=\varphi(1620-5101)+1=3423$$ which is not prime but we have $P_{n+2}-\sigma(n)=p^2$, more precisely it is a square of 59.

Interestingly for $n \leq 30 000 000$ all counterexamples have $P_{n+2}-\sigma(n)=p^2$

1. Prove that there are infinity $P_{n+2}-\sigma(n)=p^2$?
2. Prove that there are only two possibilities: the result ends with 03, 23, 43, 63 or 83 and it is a prime or the result ends with 03, 23, 43, 63 or 83 and it is not a prime. In this case $P_{n+2}-\sigma(n)=p^2$

Comment: How often do you get $F(n)\equiv3\pmod{20}$? How many $n$ up to, say, one million satisfy this congruence?

Comment: What do you mean with more detailed ? Do you want a proof that the exceptions must be odd prime powers ?

Comment: @Peter: yes This is that I want.

Comment: This is an interesting question but it may be very difficult to prove.

Comment: To summarize what needs to be proven : If $\sigma(n)=P_{n+2}$ , then $F(n)$ is not well defined , but I did not find any such case. If $n$ is not a square and not twice a square , then $\sigma(n)$ is even and therefore $|\sigma(n)-P_{n+2}|$ odd. Since the totient function of this must be of the form $4k+2$ , this implies that $|\sigma(n)-P_{n+2}|$ must be an odd prime or the power of an odd prime. Moreover this odd prime must be of the form $4k+3$.

Comment: The difficulty is the case that $n$ is a square or twice a square. In this case , $\sigma(n)$ is odd and therefore $|\sigma(n)-P_{n+2}|$ even. The totient function of this is of the form $4k+2$ , if $|\sigma(n)-P_{n+2}|$ is twice the power of a prime of the form $4k+3$. And this has not yet been ruled out.

Comment: Cross-posted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461849

Answer (score 3):

According to my calculations with PARI/GP , the smallest counterexample is $$n=526388126$$ We have $$F(n)=10549870323$$ which is not prime and $P_{n+2}-\sigma(n)=47^6$ , which is a prime power and a perfect square , but not the square of a prime !

Comment: see my above answer. I generalize the formula for prime power and not only for square prime.

Comment: Please answer my question, Rédoane: how many $n$ satisfy the congruence?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: the formula generates a very lot of prime numbers and power prime. So, I think that if $F(n) \equiv 3 \mod 20$ the result is a prime number which ends by 03, 23, 43, 63 or 83 or the result is a prime power (and not only square). So the congruence is satisfied for all n < 30 000 000 (checked with a C++ program).

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: if you means how many the result of the function ends by 03, 23, 43, 63 or 83 I have no idea for this proportion.

Comment: The conjecture concerns value of $n$ for which $F(n)\equiv3\pmod{20}$. I don't believe that $F(n)\equiv3\pmod{20}$ for all $n<30,000,000$. If $F(n)\equiv3\pmod{20}$ for only three or four values of $n<30,000,000$, then that's not very convincing evidence of the truth of the conjecture. That's why I wan't to know how many $n$ there are for which $F(n)\equiv3\pmod{20}$, before I spend any time thinking about the question. But getting this basic information from you is like pulling teeth.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson : with a simple C++ program I find about 2% of $F(n) \equiv 3 \mod 20$ of the total $F(n)$. Here you will find the 50,000 first terms (i.e the 50,000 first $F(n)$
 : http://sendeyo.com/show/c9cb89288f) Is the proportion of $F(n) \equiv 3 \mod 20$
 converges to 2%? This is a simple observation.

Comment: Thanks. That's the kind of information that should always be presented, when one makes a conjecture.

Comment: So, is this conjecture interesting? Is it difficult to prove it? I have no idea.

Comment: @Peter: can you use PARI/GP to verify if there is a counterexample or not?

Comment: This is not so easy as it sounds , but I found a method efficient enough to verify that there is no counterexample upto $n=4\cdot 10^9$ (to be more precise , upto $P_{n+2}=10^{11}$)

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ be a natural number $\geq 1$, $\varphi(n)$ is the Euler's totient function, $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of divisors of $n$.

The important result is that if n is odd and $\varphi(n)=4k+2$ then $n$ has only one prime divisor.
If we focus on numbers $a+b$ with $a$ even ($a=\sigma(k)$) and $b$ odd ($b=P_{k+2})$ the conjecture is true but we can generalize this result for all odd numbers (so this is the reason for which the formula is true with prime numbers).

Here I claim that only exceptions are $p^2$ but in reality the only exceptions are $p^k$.

Comment: This conjecture is still alive.

Comment: @Peter: you means that it has not be proved?

Comment: I have not proven it. Do you have a proof ?

Comment: @Peter: Isn't this answer a proof?

Comment: Maybe , you are right. I have to check it carefully. At least , we now know that $p^2$ is not enough , but holds quite long.

Comment: Can we rule out twice an odd prime power ?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea

Comment: Every distinct odd prime factor of $n$ introduces another factor of two into $\phi(n)$, so it's true that if $n$ is odd and $\phi(n)=4k+2$ then $n$ is a power of an odd prime. But is that enough to get the desired outcome for $F(n)$?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: thank for your message. You mean that this conjecture is still alive and has not be proved?

Comment: I don't see anything on this page that looks like a proof, Rédoane, only your frequently repeated claim.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Ok so the conjecture is still alive?

Comment: So far as I can tell, yes.